# Dynamic constraint satisfaction in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am evaluating OptaPlanner for a planning problem I have. I have seen several responses to this topic, but nothing quite like I am looking for.

I am looking for the capability to extend the problem on the fly; that is, as the planner is solving a problem.

For example, in the CloudComputing example, I would like to be able to add computers on the fly (to a point) while the problem is being solved. The easiest case is that the problem is initially over-constrained and to resolve this I would like to be able to add computers, and then replan.

Or, I would like to be able to add a lecture, or a lecturer in one of the scheduling problems, etc.

It seems like the OptaPlanner requires a static number of entities / variables at solve time.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: In the Cloudcomputing example of 6.2 you can already add computers and processes on the fly. Click on the button near the top with the green + symbol to add a computer. Processes can be added after pressing on the "details" button.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Real-time planning](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.1.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#realTimePlanning) section of the OptaPlanner User Guide.

You could also look at the Travelling Salesman Problem example in `optaplanner-examples`. Specifically, look at the `org.optaplanner.examples.tsp.swingui.TspPanel` class and traverse down from there. It's a pretty standard implementation of real-time planning AFAIK. I can also recommend to run the TSP example first to "see" how it works.